# Difference between calling a private method of class with calling as 'this.methodName' or only with 'methodName'

Tags: java, this

I have seen many implementations wherein a class (`C1`) and in this class a private method (`M1`). I have seen using `this.M1` or simply `M1` from other methods of this class to use this method `M1`.

```
public class C1{
    private void M1(){
        // do something...
    }

    public void M2(){
        this.M1();
        //OR calling as
        M1();
    }

    private void M3(){
        this.M1();
        //OR calling as
        M1();
    }
}
```

What is the proper way?

and

what is the difference?

---

EDIT

and it this anything to do with **"when multiple threads try to access the same method?"**

```
public class SingletonClass {

    private static SingletonClass singletonClass= new SingletonClass("apple");

    private String a;

    private SingletonClass(String input) {
        this.a = input;
    }

    public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        System.out.println("ha ha "+ singletonClass.a);
        return singletonClass;
    }

    public void m2(){
        System.out.println("Here");
        this.m1();
    }

    private void m1(){
        System.out.println("here");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingletonClass.getInstance().m2();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no proper way, it's more a matter of coding style

Comment: @RC: Is this to help when multiple threads try to access the same method? Why downvote?

Comment: More important naming your classes and methods doesn't have any meaning and comments are useless, also it doesn't apply to javadoc format.

Comment: @RupeshKumar No it isn't. It makes zero difference. Nobody has downvoted the question, and you wouldn't know who they were if they did.

Comment: @Rupesh see Rohit or suresh answer (and no downvote from me..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a particular coding style. In this particular case `this` is redundant as it is implied .  I use it as I find it to improve readability.  generally you would use `this` to resolve the ambiguity caused by an instance variable and local variable with same name, where the local variable shadows the instance variable :

```
public class C1{
  private int x ;
  private void M1(int x){
    this.x = x;
  }
}
```

Comment: One more is this has any relevance to threads accessing the same method. Just wondering?

Comment: @RupeshKumar I think it has nothing to do with threads. How are multiple threads accessing your method , can you show us some code for that !

Comment: @Rupeshkumar As I said `this` is redundant and implied so it doesn't make any difference in your case , even in a multithreaded environment .

Answer (score 2):

No  difference as both point's to same instance member.

And [In docs of this keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> The most common reason for using the this keyword is because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

Want to highlight that last point from docs,With out the code,its becomes invalid.So pasting directly

For example, the Point class was written like this

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
but it could have been written like this:

public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

> Each argument to the constructor shadows one of the object's fields — inside the constructor x is a local copy of the constructor's first argument. To refer to the Point field x, the constructor must use this.x.

Comment: Helpful, but would like to check for third Question too... :)

Comment: @RupeshKumar  AFAIK answer is ..`it depends` based on if  it an instance per thread or instance for many threads. Ofcourse **no**  if it is sharing among the threads.

Answer (score 0):

No difference at all.

calling `M1()` is same as `this.M1()`

Though one can argue that the latter form is more clear and readable.